# Java: placing integers first or last in a deque based on whether it is odd or even

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, deque

I have to write a program which adds integers in a deque such that the odd numbers are added last in the deque and the even numbers are added first.
I don't know where to add the if statement for the addition of the numbers and how to make my code work. 
Sorry if my codes seem to be wrong as this is my first program on deque.

```
package lesson1;
import java.util.*;


     public class MyClass1{

     public static void main(String[] args) {

     Deque<Integer> d= new LinkedList<Integer>();

     d.add(10);
     d.add(3);
     d.add(5);
     d.add(6);
     d.add(15);

     for(int i=0; i<d.size();i++){

         Integer head= d.poll();

         if(head%2==1){
             d.addLast(head);

         }

         else{
             d.addFirst(head);
         }

     }

     System.out.println(d);


  }

}
```

Comment: What about your program doesn't work? Whats the desired output and what is the current output?

Comment: I should get `[3,5,15,10,6]` but instead I am getting the numbers in the deque in the same order as they were added that is `[10,3,5,6,15]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cottonman is correct and I would indeed use a seperate Input list like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
Deque<Integer> d = new LinkedList<>();

input.add(10);
input.add(3);
input.add(5);
input.add(6);
input.add(15);

for (Integer i : input) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        d.addLast(i);
    } else {
        d.addFirst(i);
    }
}

System.out.println(d);
```

This will iterate over the `input` `ArrayList` and yield `[6, 10, 3, 5, 15]`, which is what you desire (Odd numbers last, even numbers first).

edit: To answer your question to @cottonman, it is inded possible to check while adding. To achive this, you can extend the `LinkedList` anonymously and override the `add()` method:

```
Deque<Integer> d = new LinkedList<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer integer) {
        if (integer % 2 == 1) {
            super.addLast(integer);
        } else {
            super.addFirst(integer);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

d.add(10);
d.add(3);
d.add(5);
d.add(6);
d.add(15);

System.out.println(d);
```

This will also print the desired output and every number added to the `Deque` will now be added in the desired fashion.

Comment: I haven't really understood the override method..that is what the _super_ method is calling and all..  Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: This is like extending the LinkedList class, but anonymously. You are extending the class and changing only the `add()` method in the newly created class that otherwise functions just like a normal `LinkedList`. super is used to call methods of the superclass, the class that you are extending which in this case is `LinkedList`. You are calling `LinkedList`s methods `addLast()` and `addFirst()` inside the overridden `add()` method.

Answer (score 2):

So, the reason that you're not getting the right results after the for loop is because d.poll() is retrieving (and removing) the head of the deque. Since the current head is 10 and it is even, it will be added to the head (i.e. addFirst). Now, since it's RE-added to the head of the deque, when we poll again, we are getting 10 again! So, at the end of the loop, the deque remains in the same state as before.

You have two options (IMO) here.

(1) Check whether an INTEGER/number is even/odd BEFORE adding the value to the deque.

(2) Have a separate empty deque to hold the final results in the FOR loop if you insist of adding the original values to the deque first (before doing any processing).

Either way seems pretty trivial to implement. Feel free to let me know should you have any questions regarding what I have mentioned above.

Cheer!

Comment: Thanks! I had actually thought of checking whether a number is even/odd before adding the value to the deque.. Can you tell me how it could be done?

Comment: Sure. You've already got the logic in the for loop. So, when you receive an integer in your method; let's call it N, we use an IF_ELSE statement to check whether it is ODD or EVEN. If(N % 2 == 1) --> ODD --> d.addLast(N) else EVEN --> d.addFirst(N). No need for a FOR loop. :)